# Attach image url then email using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

What is the correct syntax for emailing an image url in a row as an attachment?

I'm trying to loop through all rows within a Google Sheet and attach an image url as the image. I can send the correct subject line and message body using the below code (minus the attachment stuff below), but when I try and add the attachment stuff it doesn't let me save it and says "Missing : after property ID. (line 22, file "Code")" which is on the line that reads "attachments: attachment, blob]"

```
function sendEmails() { 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
   // Fetch the range of cells
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)  
   var data = dataRange.getValues(); 

   for (i in data) {
     var row = data[i];
     var emailAddress = "removed@gmail.com";
     var subject =  row[0];
     var message = row[1].toString();
     var attachment = UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[2]).getBlob();   

     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
       name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
       attachments: attachment, blob]  
     });  
   } // for
} // sendEmails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the blobs in an array.

```
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
   name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
   attachments: [attachment]  
 });
```

Comment: I think that will work, but in my code above the attachment variable isn't set properly. I get an error "Blob object must have non-null content type for this operation.". Alternately If I simply get the attachment like "var attachment = row[2];" I get an error "Invalid argument: inlineImages".

Comment: row[2] has to be a proper URL.

Comment: Thanks, that was one of the problems (fixed by making numcolumns dynamic), but I then hard coded the variable attachments and still got the error. I even put a valid image url directly in the sendEmail function and debug fails on the first line of that function complaining about inlineImages again.

    `GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
    attachments: ["http://placehold.it/400"]
     });`

Comment: Figured this out. I wasn't setting the blob object initially as outlined here. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28Object%29.

Once that was set then the send function looks like:
`GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
     name: 'Auto Emailer',
     inlineImages:
       {
         image: imageBlob
         
       }

 });`